# Resizing an animated image in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on an HTML/CSS/jQuery document, and part of it involves an image of a flood that moves briefly, and then swells to fill the screen until it gets clicked, at which point it reverts to its original size and fades into the background. It moves as it should, behaves properly when clicked, and *mostly* resizes properly.

My problem is that before it grows it disappears. At least, I think it's disappearing. It might be initially resizing itself to 0x0. At any rate, I can't figure out the syntax to have the resizing simply begin from the image's normal size.

Have some code! In context, this is part of a series of images which are subsequently clicked for various effects. For the record, the 'left:"20"' bit in the second .animate() is to create the illusion of the flood staying in place. That much is doing what it should. Also, because of the requirements for this project, raw javascript is to be avoided to the extent possible (but, if it's not possible, gotta do what I gotta do I suppose).

```
$("img#window").click(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith('<img id="window" src="../Kafka/chain 3/window_bw.png" style="opacity:0.35;filter:alpha(opacity=35);z-index:5;">');
    $("img#flood").show().animate({
        left: "160"
    }, 2500, function() {
        $("img#flood").animate({
            left: "20",
            width: "400%",
            height: "400%"
        }, 20000)
    });
    $("span#three").replaceWith('<span class="text" id="three">Flood</span>')
});

$("img#flood").click(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith('<img id="flood" src="../Kafka/chain 3/flood_bw.png" style="opacity:0.35;filter:alpha(opacity=35);z-index:5;">');
    $("img#stranger").show();
    $("span#three").replaceWith('<span class="text" id="three">Stranger</span>')
});​
```

Comment: so the image disappears then reappears and starts growing? is there an example we can see?

Comment: I've been working locally, so I don't have an example uploaded. But, yes, that's the gist of it. The image disappears and grows from nothing rather than its original size.

Comment: Can you post your HTML or a jsFiddle?

Comment: @Tracy I have a feeling it has something to do with the show() OR animate, it might be animating from 0-xxx%. can you create a simple fiddle if not, then try to set the dimension of the image then animate. If the image is display:none I thin it returns a width of 0 so maybe the timing of show() and animate does not sync up properly so the width when queried returned 0 so it goes from 0-target % which explains the disappearing... You will have to test it I can't say for sure that's the issue or not

Comment: It would help if you reproduced a working example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Oh wow, I'd never heard of jsFiddle before. What a nifty thing! To see the flood behavior, click the bottom-right image, and then the furthest top-left image. Since it's all broken links right now, the issue I'm referencing isn't quite apparent. Give me a minute and I'll upload the relevant ones to imgur and update the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/vhzc6/

Comment: Okay, got the images on the fiddle. Funny thing is, the flood is more or less doing what it should on there, while the problem persists on Chrome, the one I was referencing initially. I just tried Firefox for shits and giggles, and on that one the growth is instant rather than an animation. Anyway, thanks for the tips Huangism. I'll play around with that :)

Comment: Can you update the fiddle with the full path to the images you're using? BTW, if you want to reply to someone so they receive a notification, be sure to use the @username syntax. Otherwise they won't know you replied.

Comment: Please change your image src in your fiddle with this path: http://www.placehold.it/350x200 (for example), in that way we can see images and what happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out and tell me. Can you make a jsfiddle page and share if it does not work. 
I will tell you what I am trying to do here.Basically, rather than telling jQuery to make the size 400%, I am telling it to increase the size by 300%(Assuming it is at 100% at the point of time).If it is not at 100% change the value 300 accordingly.

```
$("img#window").click(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith('<img id="window" src="../Kafka/chain 3/window_bw.png" style="opacity:0.35;filter:alpha(opacity=35);z-index:5;">');
    $("img#flood").show().animate({
        left: "160"
    }, 2500, function() {
        $("img#flood").animate({
            left: "20",
            width: "+=300%",
            height: "+=300%"
        }, 20000)
    });
    $("span#three").replaceWith('<span class="text" id="three">Flood</span>')
});

$("img#flood").click(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith('<img id="flood" src="../Kafka/chain 3/flood_bw.png" style="opacity:0.35;filter:alpha(opacity=35);z-index:5;">');
    $("img#stranger").show();
    $("span#three").replaceWith('<span class="text" id="three">Stranger</span>')
});​
```